# Google OAuth2 redirect_uri_mismatch Issue

Tags: python, django, google-api

All,

Im getting a 400 redirect_url_mismatch error upon attempting to authenticate through google. I'm using python-socal-auth through a django application to achieve this process.

Everything works smoothly, until I get to the final stages of the process where I hit a redirect_uri_mismatch issue.

On google, I receive this message.

`"The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8000/something/complete/google-oauth2/ did not match a registered redirect URI"`

```
`Request Details
from_login=1
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/something/complete/google-oauth2/
state=qT1RLLMa72F8NxFFubHwCVe3GgLDNcgZ
as=-55f896f3314b21af
pli=1
client_id=160177117398
authuser=0
hl=en`
```

Included below is a screenshot of the client ID's redirect URI.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One thing to note here is that redirect url should be exactly same till the last trailing slash.  In my case, it was like http://localhot:8000/something/complete/google-oauth2
This should have been
http://localhot:8000/something/complete/google-oauth2/
This resulted in redirect_uri_mismatch.

Also define http: and https: in the console for redirect url because redirect url generated by social auth still sends http regardless of ssl setting in your server.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you added the social-auth in the urls.py as

```
url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
```

and on console.developers.google.com set the `Authorized redirect URIs` to `http://localhost:8000/something/complete/google-oauth2/`

Comment: thanks, the last / on `google-oauth2/` was what I was missing.